# Cannot run git clone or pip install commands

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cmd

So i'm pretty new to the whole windows repo cloning thing. I installed python 2.7, added the path to my windows cmd and I still cannot run any git clone commands. It shows the following output :

git clone
  File "", line 1
    git clone
            ^

I've been scouring the internet for an answer but apparently it should work if I use cmd. 
Any help would be appreciated!

git clone
  File "", line 1
    git clone
            ^

Comment: first, lets solve python 2.7. Start by seeing if python exe is present on path variables or not i.e. if you type python in a newly opened cmd, it should open python console. If that is fixed, then install pip. There are a ton of documents. once Python is fixed. Simply remove git completely and re-install

Comment: @ManishMishra Yes, I have my path set. I can open CMD and it returns the python console with the version when I type in python and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue recently with 3.7, so I made a new username and it worked. Kind of nice, a clean new Windows profile, even though I just started using it again compared to linux. A pain though.

Make sure all other versions of Python are not installed, or at least affecting the path to the file you need the pip installs to be saved. Python can be saved in a few different locations, and some rare times it has been shown in very obscure places. Check where your file saved on your PC. Probablu C:/ then could be many paths. /Users/UnserNameHere/Windows/ProgramFiles. I would use the search bar in the good old GUI while searching under the C drive (if you have multiple HDD/SDD then pic the one used for the C drive, if nothing comes up try the other drives.

Your looking for a file PythonFoundation I can't remember the entire name, however it will have a very long name Python Foundation are in the name of the file. This is where thing are store and where the path should be sending modules, at least the correct file inside that file.

Also try doing it from other Python versions installed. If you had 3.6 and got 3.7 it doesn't mean 3.6 has been deleted. Also doesn't mean you path, is not set to 3.6 while using 3.7. Same with Python 2, most people or many have both. The pip commands vary between python versions pip3 I believe is used (getting windows and linux a little mixed up right now)

If all fails do it the old fashon way, find the mod, download it, and move it to the python file I mentioned above. The homepage for python should have a tab linking to a page, or it's on the main page, letting you know where it has been known to save. Google how to see he path Pip is taking, or how to see if pip is installed and where, and what paths are set to.